# HTML5 local storage not storing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if I have understood the right context of 'storage', but according to some tutorials I used the following Javascript code, to enable a page to locally store (no session) submitted data, but when I close the page and reopen the page, the content do not appear.

#### script.js

```
function initiate()
{
   var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
   var retrieveButton = document.getElementById('retrieve');
   var deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete');
   var reviewButton = document.getElementById('review');

   saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveItem);
   retrieveButton.addEventListener('click', retrieveItem);
   deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
   reviewButton.addEventListener('click', reviewAll);

}

function saveItem()
{
    var key = document.getElementById('key').value;
    var value = document.getElementById('value').value;
    localStorage[key] = value; 
}

function retrieveItem()
{
    var data = document.getElementById('data');
    var key = document.getElementById('key').value;
    var value = localStorage[key];
    data.innerHTML = '<div>' + key + ': ' + value + '</div>';
}

function deleteItem()
{
    if (confirm('Delete?'))
    {
        var key = document.getElementById('key').value;
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        data.innerHTML = '<div>Deleted.</div>';
    }    
}

function reviewAll()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
    {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        var value = localStorage[key];
        data.innerHTML += '<div>' + key + ': ' + value + '<br></div>';

    }
}


addEventListener("load", initiate);
```

#### index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Demo HTML5</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="formSection">
            <form name="dataForm">
                <label for="key">Key: </label><br />
                <input type="text" id="key" name="key" /> <br />
                 <label for="value">Value: </label><br />
                <textarea name="value" id="value"></textarea><br />
                 <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
                <input type="button" id="retrieve" value="Retrieve" /> 
                <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" />
                 <input type="button" id="review" value="Review" />             
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="data">
            No data
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first you must check if your browser supports localstorage `if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("varname","data" );
} else {
   alert ("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}`

Comment: @Farshad Yes. It does support storage. It actually stores it, until the browser is closed.

Comment: If you want to retain the value even after the page close action. you can use cookies

Comment: @Farshad I thought local storage achieve that, without the need to use cookies.

Comment: yes , this feature is added in HTML5. I found this article and code sample for using html5 localstorage [Halma Game](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/localstorage-halma.html)

Comment: Works ok in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tqum3coo/1/

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin But I can't retrieve anything. If it worked, then should it not show some data?

Comment: Well, I checked in Chrome (don't have other browsers right now). What browser do you use?

Comment: I use firefox 31.0 It is the latest version.

Comment: Did you actually enter any data? Because I can't view anything

Comment: I've just checked in FF 31 - entered Key = "123", Value = "456", pressed Save. Then I pressed "Run" on jsfiddle menu to reset the values, entered "123" in the Key field and pressed "Retrieve" -> under the Value text box appeared "123: 456"

Comment: Same here when converting the codes into a document and clearing the cache by means of a reload with Ctrl + F5 -- when after that reload '123' is entered as the requested key, '456' is given as value.

Comment: Disabling cookies in FF appears also to disable localStorage.  Do you have cookies disabled? http://superuser.com/questions/629525/how-to-control-websites-use-of-localstorage-in-firefox

Comment: @BobBrown Nope. I never disable the cookies. I am still wandering if this method is tested on all browsers. Because, I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: I've tested localStorage pretty thoroughly in Firefox 30/31 and somewhat less thoroughly in Chrome 35 and Internet Explorer 11. Others have reported that the fiddle works for them.  That points to _something_ about your browser configuration.  Is your browser set to clear cookies on close?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: No my browser is actually fine. Nothing different from the default install. I am still wandering though, if I have understood the concept of "Local storage". Say, now you store something then you close your browser and restart your PC, are you then able to retrieve those contents later on? If yes, then it definitely has something to do with my browser/pc

Comment: Yes, you understand localStorage correctly.  Try this: go to http://bbrown.spsu.edu/tlc/ and click the "Save" button in the middle of the page.  Close and re-open your browser, and go to: http://bbrown.spsu.edu/tlc/assembler.html  The saved data should be available in the "Load" select box; selecting "posdiff" and clicking "Load" should make it appear in the left pane.  (The actual function of the page isn't important, but it does use localStorage and persists across invocations of the browser in every browser I've tested.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the browser in privacy mode, it will clear all localStorage data when you close it.

Comment: No. I am not on privacy mode. I don't think this local storage function is reliable though